# Perform facial recognition offline in android app

Tags: android, amazon-rekognition, facial-identification

I am building an android app which will authenticate user with AWS Rekognition facial verification. The app might be running in remote areas where internet and cellular connectivity are not available.

It it possible to pre-download all the face metadata stored in AWS and perform facial verification offline in the android app?

Comment: Since you mention 'authentication', it may help to read how Android does authentication on-device: https://source.android.com/security/authentication?hl=en and https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure?hl=en or perhaps expand on what problem you are solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to run Amazon Rekognition's logic locally on your device.

When the device is offline, you could use [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces), or [TensorFlow Lite](https://medium.com/@estebanuri/real-time-face-recognition-with-android-tensorflow-lite-14e9c6cc53a5).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible :(

Even if it were possible, it would not be safe to place the authentication responsibility on local device.